# Code coverage for Robot framework where application written in C++

Tags: testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, robotframework

I have a scenario like this - Application written in hybrid languages (Python, C++ and Java majorly). There are around 100 test cases written in Robot framework to test the application. Now I want to see code coverage of my application. Is there any tool that can work in such scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The same way you would do outside robotframework: Using external code analysis tools. Let me elaborate.

In Python, you can use tools like Coverage (https://pypi.org/project/coverage) to run your testing suite while gathering coverage data. For example, if you usually run your robot test suites using:

```
robot suites
```

(supposing you have a "suites" directory with your .robot files) then you would run robot as a Python module over Coverage like this:

```
coverage run -m robot suites
```

And you could get your report with:

```
coverage report
```

You'll probably need to filter the report (--include option) if you're only interested in code inside a directory. For example, for a directory "myproy" you would do:

```
coverage report --include *myproy/*
```

You could use a similar strategy with other Python test coverage tools as long as you figure out how to tweak their execution command to run robot as a module. The same holds for C++ and Java code analysis tools; For example, check the following link for a guide that uses Java with JaCoCo and Maven: https://www.cnblogs.com/z1500592/p/6676646.html

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the methodology by @DanyAlejandro but unfortunately upon testing I found the following in the [coverage.py docs](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.7/source.html#execution):

> Files that do not end with .py, .pyw, .pyo, or .pyc will also be skipped

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that this module is capable of analyzing code coverage for `.robot` files.

Comment: It is better to write this as a comment